# how to switch cart items & totals table?

Tags: magento2, knockoutjs

how to switch positions of cart items & totals table, move cart items to the top and then totals table to the bottom

[image]

```
<!-- ko foreach: elems() -->
     <pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON(getTemplate(), null, 2)"></pre>
    <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
<!-- /ko -->
```

and how to debug "elems()" sequence?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.First override checkout_index_index.xml under your theme like Package/Theme/Magento_Checkout/layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
   <body>
       <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
           <arguments>
               <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                   <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                       <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                           <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                               <item name="sidebar" xsi:type="array">
                                  <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">50</item>
                                  <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/js/view/sidebar</item>
                                  <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">sidebar</item>
                                  <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                      <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/sidebar</item>
                                      <item name="deps" xsi:type="array">
                                          <item name="0" xsi:type="string">checkout.steps</item>
                                      </item>
                                  </item>
                                  <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                      <item name="summary" xsi:type="array">
                                          <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/js/view/summary</item>
                                          <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">summary</item>
                                          <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                              <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/summary</item>
                                          </item>
                                          <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                              <item name="itemsBefore" xsi:type="array">
                                                  <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
                                                  <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                      <!-- merge your components here -->
                                                  </item>
                                              </item>
                                              <item name="cart_items" xsi:type="array">
                                                  <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/js/view/summary/cart-items</item>
                                                  <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                      <item name="details" xsi:type="array">
                                                          <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/js/view/summary/item/details</item>
                                                          <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                              <item name="thumbnail" xsi:type="array">
                                                                  <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/js/view/summary/item/details/thumbnail</item>
                                                                  <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">before_details</item>
                                                              </item>
                                                              <item name="subtotal" xsi:type="array">
                                                                  <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/js/view/summary/item/details/subtotal</item>
                                                                  <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">after_details</item>
                                                              </item>
                                                          </item>
                                                      </item>
                                                  </item>
                                              </item>
                                              <item name="itemsAfter" xsi:type="array">
                                                  <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
                                                  <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                      <!-- merge your components here -->
                                                  </item>
                                              </item>
                                              <item name="totals" xsi:type="array">
                                                  <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/js/view/summary/totals</item>
                                                  <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">totals</item>
                                                  <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                      <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/summary/totals</item>
                                                  </item>
                                                  <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                      <!-- sort order for this totals is configured on admin panel-->
                                                      <!-- Stores->Configuration->SALES->Sales->General->Checkout Totals Sort Order -->
                                                      <item name="subtotal" xsi:type="array">
                                                          <item name="component"  xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/js/view/summary/subtotal</item>
                                                          <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                              <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Cart Subtotal</item>
                                                          </item>
                                                      </item>
                                                      <item name="shipping" xsi:type="array">
                                                          <item name="component"  xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/js/view/summary/shipping</item>
                                                          <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                              <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Shipping</item>
                                                              <item name="notCalculatedMessage" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Not yet calculated</item>
                                                          </item>
                                                      </item>
                                                      <item name="grand-total" xsi:type="array">
                                                          <item name="component"  xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/js/view/summary/grand-total</item>
                                                          <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                              <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Order Total</item>
                                                          </item>
                                                      </item>
                                                  </item>
                                              </item>
                                          </item>
                                      </item>
                                      <item name="shipping-information" xsi:type="array">
                                          <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/js/view/shipping-information</item>
                                          <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                              <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">checkout.steps.shipping-step.shippingAddress</item>
                                          </item>
                                          <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">shipping-information</item>
                                          <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                              <item name="ship-to" xsi:type="array">
                                                  <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/js/view/shipping-information/list</item>
                                                  <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">ship-to</item>
                                              </item>
                                          </item>
                                      </item>
                                  </item>
                              </item>
                           </item>
                       </item>
                   </item>
               </argument>
           </arguments>
       </referenceBlock>
   </body>
</page>
```

Now check on your onepage checkout.See screen shot
[image]

Answer (score 0):

i considered @Charul Tyagi as correct answer, but I have better answer, in checkout_index_index.xml use this xml at your theme

```
    <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="sidebar" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="summary" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="totals" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">99</item>
                                            </item>
                                            <item name="cart_items" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">0</item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </referenceBlock>
```